# New to access data macros

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can i rely on access data macros to always work reliably? Or should i just carry on with calculated fields and expressions in queries. I'm want to use them to calculate invoice totals on the after insert, after update and after delete events on invoice item records. thanks for any feedback.

Have implemented them but want to know that they'll always give me the right answer going forward.

Comment: IMO for things that can easily be calculated, that's always the better way.

Comment: Thanks Andre. I really only want to implement them to speed up my forms, as displaying too many invoices at once and they really slow down due to calculation of invoice totals.

Comment: Don't save invoice totals, do this aggregate calc from transaction records when needed for report output.

Comment: So I can't really rely on data macros being 100% accurate? It's interesting because i'm trying to copy how Sage Line 50, which is the main accounting package in the UK, does things, where it stores the invoice total plus loads of other aggregated info in header records generated from many different records